# UserControl, PlaceHolder and UpdatePanel On PostBack

Tags: asp.net, updatepanel, user-controls, placeholder

I dynamically load a `User Control`, with an `Update Panel` inside a `Place Holder`.

When I click a button from the `User Control`, should refresh the `Update Panel` contents, but it refresh the entire page instead, and the User Control is disappearing from the page, because the page's `Page_Load` does not load anything if it's a `PostBack`.

How I can fix it?

Answer (score 2):

Whenever a partial or full postback happen , Automatically all update() method of all updatepanels fire . For preventing such this behavior  you need to set `UpdateMode="Conditional"` property . In this situation you need to specify `asynchronous trigger` Or `ChildrenAsTriggers=true` .

for preventing a dynamically loaded-usercontrol to be disappear ,It's good to save it in ViewState ,  [Here is a tutorial and sample application](http://geekswithblogs.net/rashid/archive/2007/08/11/Loading-UserControl-Dynamically-in-UpdatePanel.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll need to reinject the control in page_load or pre_render.  Dynamically created controls don't live through postback.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are creating the control EVERY page request, regardless of GET/POST.  Also, make sure you are giving it the same ID.

I like to override the CreateChildControls method.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the control page to the page in the page_init method. It has to be added on each post back. The control will retain all the values even after adding it back.

[There is a full working example at this link.](http://blog.regencysoftware.com/post/2012/11/14/Dynamically-Adding-User-Controls-to-an-ASPX-page)